# Check if shapefile Polygon has a valid number of points - Python

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, shapely, well-known-text

I'm trying to create a polygon from `ShapefileReader.shapes()` object in python using the `shapely.wkt` library. But I'm having the followeing error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4
```

Is there anyway to create a valid Polygon before parsing it? I know that `ShapefileReader.shapes()` returns a String object, so how can I check this String to see if it will create a valid polygon, or even better, if there's a way to force it to create a valid polygon?

Comment: If you post some example code that reproduces the problem we'll be able to better help.  As for checking to see if it will create a valid polygon, you're almost already doing that-- just use a `try/except` block to handle that exception

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @mikewatt, that a good way to handle the error would be to capture it by using `try` and `catch`.

But if you want to check that condition, you could do something like this,

```
def correctPolygon(s):
    geoj = s.__geo_interface__
    coords = geoj['coordinates']
    # check if it is a polygon
    if geoj['type'] != 'Polygon':
        return False
    # check condition in each ring
    for rings in coords:
        for ring in rings:
            if len(ring) < 4:
                return False
    return True

s = sf.shape(0)
if correctPolygon(s):
    # your code
```